# How to add the coordinate field data into the link.csv according to the node.csv?

Tags: python

Here I have two CSV files: node.csv and link.csv, which are shown by the following TWO figures.
[node.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW4F7.png)

[link.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB4UX.png)

Now I want to do: add x-coordinate and y-coordinate information into the link.csv, according to the info provided by node.csv. The effect can be referred to as the following figure.
[Add from_node_coord_x and from_node_coord_y into the link.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCT3F.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think there will be many different ways, one of the ways to combine two files could be like below;

| link_id | from_node_id | to_node_id | length | from_node_coord | to_node_coord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 9.08 | -109.787, 34.34129 | -109.787, 34.34312 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 9.08 | -109.788, 34.34126 | -109.786, 34.34128 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

You can use power query on Excel, or import files on database and create a new table by query as well.
But if you want to use excel func only, You can use this way.
[Sheet1:link data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm4tY.png)
[Sheet2:node data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5WLa.png)

I added the sample data you posted as the figure1 and figure2, and I used function CONCAT, INDEX, MATCH, which is

> =CONCAT(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$C$6,MATCH(Sheet1!B3,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6), 1), ", ",INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$C$6,MATCH(Sheet1!B3,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6), 2))

, at Column E and F on sheet1 to get each coordinates from sheet2.

[Shee1:after using 3 function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR4eb.png)

I used concat function for just combining x and y coordinates as a string.
So you can use that separately if you want.

Comment: Really appreciate your help!